# Active record Undefined method `eq'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've table tournaments with fields user_id,question_id,answer and I created key like

```
Primary key (user_id, question_id)
```

But when I want to change answer field like this:

```
t=Tournament.where('question_id=200').first
t.answer=2
t.save
```

I've got error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `eq' for nil:NilClass
    from /home/marat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in `method_missing'
    from /home/marat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:255:in `update'
    from /home/marat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.4/lib/active_record/locking/optimistic.rb:77:in `update'
    from /home/marat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.4/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:68:in `update'
    from /home/marat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.4/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:60:in `update'
    from /home/marat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.4/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:285:in `block in update'
    from /home/marat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:413:in `_run_update_callbacks'
    from /home/marat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.4/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:285:in `update'
    from /home/marat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:246:in `create_or_update'
    from /home/marat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.4/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:277:in `block in create_or_update'
    from /home/marat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:423:in `_run_save_callbacks'
    from /home/marat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.4/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:277:in `create_or_update'
    from /home/marat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:56:in `save!'
    from /home/marat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.4/lib/active_record/validations.rb:49:in `save!'
    from /home/marat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.4/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:30:in `save!'
    from /home/marat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:245:in `block in save!'
    from /home/marat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:292:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
    from /home/marat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:139:in `transaction'
    from /home/marat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:207:in `transaction'
    from /home/marat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:290:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
    from /home/marat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:245:in `save!'
    from (irb):4
    from /home/marat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
    from /home/marat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /home/marat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
```

Can anyone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Paste whole stack trace of that exception, not just the exception itself.  This will show you what internal bit of code it's actually failing on.

Comment: This problem only exists when I want to update some row. For the first time row insertion was fine.

Comment: Solved with gem https://github.com/drnic/composite_primary_keys

Comment: Not a solution for your problem but `Tournament.find_by_question_id(200)` would do the same as `Tournament.where('question_id=200').first`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you modify your tables at all from a standard Rails genearated one?

if so, see [undefined method `eq' for nil:NilClass with rails 3 and ruby enterprise on ubuntu hardy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124290/undefined-method-eq-for-nilnilclass-with-rails-3-and-ruby-enterprise-on-ubuntu)