# How can I delete some data from DB if there is no primary key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using RoR 3.0.7. (ruby 1.9.2)

I have a table books (model Book) with following fields:

book_id - int (not a primary key)

cover_pic - varchar

year - year

I need to delete * rows from DB with books_id = 1 for example.

Have tried:

1) Book.where(:book_id=>1).destroy  (nothing)

2) Book.destroy( Book.where(:book_id=>1) ) (nothing)

3) 
Book.where(:book_id=>1).each do |obj|

obj.destroy

end

NOTHING .. =(

what am I doing wrong?

thx.

**UPD**

worked fine delete_all

interesting info:
[undefined method `eq' for nil:NilClass with rails 3 and ruby enterprise on ubuntu hardy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124290/undefined-method-eq-for-nilnilclass-with-rails-3-and-ruby-enterprise-on-ubuntu)

Comment: Are you using any gems, or is this vanilla rails?

Comment: standart gems... just updated gems with gem update --system && gem update... now have rails 3.0.9 but have the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either of these two:

This will fire all destroy callbacks

```
Book.destroy_all( :book_id => 1 )
```

This won't

```
Book.delete_all( :book_id => 1 )
```

Comment: `destroy_all` actually won't work without a primary_key defined for the table. That is why you are seeing the `undefined method `eq' for nil:NilClass` error

Comment: It doesn't work without PK! Use delete_all(attr: val) instead

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have *some* unique index on the table, this works great:

```
book = Book.first
Book.delete_all(book.attributes)
```

If you don't have a unique index on the table, the above is **dangerous** - you could nuke more rows than anticipated.  If that is the case, either add a unique index on an existing column (or columns) or else add a PK to the table.