# Updating/Saving an attribute in a join model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a join model called `AppServer` which references three other models called `Environment`, `Server` and `App`. I also added another field in the `AppServer` model called `app_server_id`, as I set `id => false` for the `AppServer` model. I added the `app_server_id` field at a later stage, after having populated the table and not getting any further with my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145339/editing-viewing-destroying-a-join-table-item).

So since I now have `app_server_id`, I tried to populate it, using the following method in the `AppServer` model:

```
def generate_id
  "#{environment_id}_#{app_id}_#{server_id}"
end
```

however, in the rails console I wanted to see whether the method works so I done this:

```
pry(main)> AppServer.first.generate_id
=> "2_3_1"
```

So now trying either to update the attribute or save it won't work as shown:

```
pry(main)> AppServer.first.app_server_id = AppServer.first.generate_id
=> "2_3_1"
pry(main)> AppServer.first.app_server_id
=> nil
```

or

```
pry(main)> AppServer.first.update_attribute(:app_server_id, AppServer.first.generate_id)
NoMethodError: undefined method `eq' for nil:NilClass
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in `method_missing'
```

or even

```
pry(main)> apps=AppServer.first
=> #<AppServer app_id: 3, server_id: 1, environment_id: 2, app_server_id: nil>
pry(main)> apps.app_server_id = apps.generate_id
=> "2_3_1"
pry(main)> apps.save
NoMethodError: undefined method `eq' for nil:NilClass
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in `method_missing'
```

Any idea why that could be?

If you guys need any more code let me know

Comment: why does your IRB prompt say 'pry' ?

Comment: @banister That's because I'm using a different REPL as opposed to IRB. check it out [on RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/280-pry-with-rails?autoplay=true)

Comment: is it good? what do you think of that new REPL so far?

Comment: @banister I tried it out for a bit and I think it's amazing in comparison to IRB. you get things such as auto-complete, debug mode, CD'ing into models and so forth. Check out the video on the Pry wiki, that made me change my REPL to pry ;)

Comment: cool, which features do you like best about it?

Comment: @banister almost everything about it is great. Just so much more feature rich than IRB

Answer (score 1):

This

```
pry(main)> AppServer.first.app_server_id = AppServer.first.generate_id
=> "2_3_1"
pry(main)> AppServer.first.app_server_id
=> nil
```

doesn't work because you're assigning the app_server_id, not saving it, then referencing the saved version (nil) again.

For this

```
undefined method `eq' for nil:NilClass
```

see this question

[undefined method `eq' for nil:NilClass with rails 3 and ruby enterprise on ubuntu hardy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124290/undefined-method-eq-for-nilnilclass-with-rails-3-and-ruby-enterprise-on-ubuntu)

Edit

I see no benefit not to auto increment this so I would add an id column using this migration and remove your to_param method:

```
def self.up
  execute "ALTER TABLE 'app_servers'
              ADD COLUMN 'id' INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL FIRST,
              ADD PRIMARY KEY('id')"
end
```

[Credit where due](http://bilsonrails.wordpress.com/2008/05/22/adding-an-auto-increment-field-to-a-table-with-existing-data-in-mysql/)

Comment: ok but in my code I have also used another approach where I call the `save` method, but even that doesn't work

Comment: The save and update_attribute are both causing the same error which I linked to another related question. My advice is to add an id column to your join table.

Comment: which is what I tried to do. I created `app_server_id` which is supposed to be my table's ID so i can access it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I meant a primary key auto incrementing id column. I briefly read over your other question and you're straying way too far from convention, this is the type of thing that rails doesn't like. :)

Comment: ooops, is that my mistake? so how would I go about changing my already populated table to have an ID column? And does it have to be automatically incremented or can I use my `generate_id` method?

Comment: tried many times but I get this error message:'rake db:migrate
PopulateAppServerId: migrating 
-- execute("ALTER TABLE 'app_servers' \n      ADD COLUMN 'app_server_id' INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL FIRST, \n
ADD PRIMARY KEY('app_server_id')")
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
ODBC::Error: 37000 (102) [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'app_servers'.: ALTER TABL
E 'app_servers'
      ADD COLUMN 'app_server_id' INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL FIRST,
      ADD PRIMARY KEY('app_server_id')
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate'

Comment: @teenOmar let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2767/discussion-between-mark-and-teenomar)