# Why do I get a undefined method `join' for nil:NilClass error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this code in my "index.html.erb" file in my project:

```
<h1>Listing businesses</h1>

<table>
<tr>
    <th>Index</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Phone Number</th>
    <th>Suite</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>City</th>
<th>Province</th>
<th>Postal Code</th>
<th>Fax</th>
    <th>Latitude</th>
    <th>Longitude</th>
    <th>Website</th>
    </tr>

<% count = 0 %>
<% @businesses.each do |business| %>
<!--<%=business.inspect %> <br> <br>-->
<%count = count.to_i + 1 %> 
<tr>
    <td><%= count %></td>
    <td><%= business.name %></td>
    <td><%= business.phone %></td>
    <td><%= business.suite %></td>
    <td><%= business.address %></td>
    <td><%= business.city %></td>
    <td><%= business.province %></td>
    <td><%= business.phone %></td>
    <td><%= business.postalcode %></td>
    <td><%= business.fax %></td>
    <td><%= business.latitude %></td>
    <td><%= business.longitude %></td>
    <td><%= business.website %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', business %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_business_path(business) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', user, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

When I go to this url:

```
http://localhost:3000/businesses/
```

I'm getting this error:

```
NoMethodError in Businesses#index

Showing /Users/AM/Documents/RailsWS/cmdLineWS/Directory/app/views/businesses/index.html.erb where line #37 raised:

undefined method `join' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #37):

34:     <td><%= business.latitude %></td>
35:     <td><%= business.longitude %></td>
36:     <td><%= business.website %></td>
37:     <td><%= link_to 'Show', business %></td>
38:     <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_business_path(business) %></td>
39:     <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', user, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %></td>
40:   </tr>
Rails.root: /Users/AM/Documents/RailsWS/cmdLineWS/Directory
```

Any idea whats going on?

Here is the full call stack:

```
activemodel (3.2.1) lib/active_model/conversion.rb:52:in `to_param'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:417:in `block in <class:Generator>'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/formatter.rb:31:in `call'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/formatter.rb:31:in `block (2 levels) in generate'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/formatter.rb:30:in `each'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/formatter.rb:30:in `block in generate'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/formatter.rb:58:in `match_route'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/formatter.rb:16:in `generate'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:510:in `generate'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:551:in `generate'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:576:in `url_for'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb:148:in `url_for'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb:107:in `url_for'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:202:in `business_path'
app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:37:in `block in _app_views_businesses_index_html_erb___1138300221443858101_2152537040'
app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:20:in `each'
app/views/businesses/index.html.erb:20:in `_app_views_businesses_index_html_erb___1138300221443858101_2152537040'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `block in render'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:125:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:40:in `block in render_template'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:48:in `render_with_layout'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:39:in `render_template'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:12:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:109:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:225:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:28:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:50:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:88:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms'
/Users/AM/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:310:in `realtime'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block in render'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:83:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:268:in `block in retrieve_response_from_mimes'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:195:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:195:in `respond_to'
app/controllers/businesses_controller.rb:5:in `index'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run__4378774651029744650__process_action__1974792849221574797__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:205:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:66:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:66:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:30:in `call'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:589:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:443:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__539745845193235082__call__2953064504705011211__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53:in `call'
railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/Users/AM/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
/Users/AM/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
/Users/AM/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
```

Model for the app is file called business.rb it contains this:

```
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection "Listings_development"
end
```

Comment: Do you override `to_key` in your model? What does `business.to_key` return?

Comment: It'd be great if you could post the Model code for `Business` :)

Comment: @summea the model code of the business has been added to the post

Comment: @Andrew Marshall I haven't overridden the business.to_key method. I just tested the output for that method, its empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your table does not seem to have a primary key, read the [Rails Migrations Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#changing-tables) and write one to add the `id` column to your table.

```
def change
  add_column :business, :id, :primary_key
end
```

---

As described [in the documentation of the `to_param` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Conversion.html#method-i-to_param), it returns `nil` if your object has not yet been persisted.

This is because a link to an object that is not in the database is actually a broken link. Make sure your object is being saved before attempting to link to it.

---

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show', business %></td>
```

That's likely to be the problem. <s>[You must link to an URL](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to), not to a model</s>. Use a helper to obtain one that refers to the object:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show', business_path(business) %></td>
```

The same problem will occur here, I suppose:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', user, ... %></td>
```

You should replace that line with:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', destroy_user_path(user), ... %></td>
```

Comment: No that doesnt seem to be the problem

Comment: @banditKing, can you post the full call stack?

Comment: @banditKing: please don't edit somebody else's answer to add the call stack.  Please edit your question and add it there instead.

Comment: @Matheus Moreira 
Thanks. I just posted the full call stack.

Comment: You can actually pass `link_to` a model object. There's even an [example in the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to-label-Examples) you linked `:)`.

Comment: ... @AndrewMarshall, you're right. I can't believe I missed that. `:S`

Comment: @Matheus Moreira. I tried that approach. It still is not working. That doesnt seem to be the problem. Could the problem be related to the fact that in this rails app I replaced the original slite3 file with one that I brought in from my previous app. It had prepopulated values.

Comment: So I found out the problem might be somehow similar to this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124290/undefined-method-eq-for-nilnilclass-with-rails-3-and-ruby-enterprise-on-ubunt

Im trying to figure it out now...

Comment: @banditKing, it could be. In the question's comments, you said the value returned by `to_key` was blank. I guess that could be caused by invalid records in your database. Back up your old database file and run all migrations again to ensure you schema is up to date.

Comment: @banditKing, yeah, now that you mention it, is the primary key in your `business` table named `id`? If not, Rails won't be able to infer, and you will need to tell it explicitly.

Comment: The problem is that my db table does not have the id column set so there is no primary key for each row. How and where do I set the primary key in the database in rails and how to tell the model about it? If I can do this then each record will have an id and thus the edit and destroy functions that I am trying to use will be able to pull up the particular business... any suggestions would be awesome   Is there any tutorials on this please- thanks

Comment: Glad that you guys found the primary key issue :)

Comment: I had the same error even though my tables have primary keys named `:id`. But I'm using a `:select` method in a named scope and had neglected to include the `id` column in the list of selected columns. Adding `id` to the list eliminated the error. So:  not only does the table have to contain the `id` column, the `id` column has to make it back to the controller!